# Regex with sed command to parse json text

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, regex

I have this json text:

```
{
    "buildStatus" : {
        "status" : "ERROR",
        "conditions" : [{
                "status" : "OK",
                "metricKey" : "bugs"
            }, {
                "status" : "ERROR",
                "metricKey" : "test_success_density"
            }, {
                "status" : "OK",
                "metricKey" : "vulnerabilities"
            }
        ],
        "periods" : []
    }
}
```

I want to extract the overall status of the buildStatus, i.e the expected output was "ERROR"

```
"buildStatus" : {
    "status" : "ERROR",
    ....
}
```

I tried the sed expression below, but it isn't working, it returns `OK`:

```
status= sed -E 's/.*\"buildStatus\":.*\"status\":\"([^\"]*)\",.*/\1/' jsonfile
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do not parse complex nested data structures like JSON or XML with regular expressions, use a proper JSON parser, like `jshon`.

First you need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install jshon
```

Then you have to provide it the JSON data to parse via standard input, so you can either redirect another command's output there with a pipe (`|`) or redirect a file to it (`< filename`).

The arguments it needs to extract the data you want look like this:

```
jshon -e "buildStatus" -e "status" -u
```

- `-e "buildStatus"` picks the element with the "buildStatus" index from the top level dictionary.
- `-e "status"` picks the element with the "status" index from the second level dictionary picked above.
- `-u` converts the selected data from JSON to plain data (i.e. here it removes the quotes around the string)

So the command you run, depending on where you get the data from, looks like one of those:

```
jshon -e "buildStatus" -e "status" -u < YOUR_INPUT_FILE
YOUR_JSON_PRODUCING_COMMAND | jshon -e "buildStatus" -e "status" -u
```

To learn more about `jshon`, you can read its manpage accessible online [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/jshon.1.html) or by simply typing `man jshon`.

Comment: There's also [`jq`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/jq): `jq -r .buildStatus.status`

Comment: [This is what happens when you try to parse non-regular languages with regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5684257)

Comment: @HTNW I've never liked that answer, because "single XML open tag" (which is what the question asking) _is_ a regular language (and you could in principle build a full XML parser by using regexes to match tags, comments, cdata sections, and using a simple stack to handle the nested context). However, the most 'interesting' regular language in JSON is a string literal.

Answer (score 10):

Job for `jq`:

```
jq -r '.["buildStatus"]["status"]' file.json
```

Can be shortened to:

```
jq -r '.buildStatus.status' file.json
```

`-r` (`--raw-output`) outputs the string without `json` string formatting i.e. without quotes.

**Example:**

```
% cat file.json                   
{
    "buildStatus" : {
        "status" : "ERROR",
        "conditions" : [{
                "status" : "OK",
                "metricKey" : "bugs"
            }, {
                "status" : "ERROR",
                "metricKey" : "test_success_density"
            }, {
                "status" : "OK",
                "metricKey" : "vulnerabilities"
            }
        ],
        "periods" : []
    }
}

% jq -r '.["buildStatus"]["status"]' file.json
ERROR

% jq -r '.buildStatus.status' file.json       
ERROR
```

---

If not installed already, install it by (available in the Universe repository):

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

Answer (score 8):

As has been mentioned, parsing complex structured data is preferable with appropriate API. Python has `json` module for that , which I personally use quite a lot in my scripts, and it's quite easy to extract the desired fields you want as so:

```
$ python -c 'import sys,json;print json.load(sys.stdin)["buildStatus"]["status"]' <  input.txt
ERROR
```

What happens here is that we redirect input file to python's stdin, and read that with `json.load()`. That becomes a python dictionary with key "buildStatus", and it contains another python dictionary with "status" key. Thus, we're merely are printing out value of a key in a dictionary that is stored within another dictionary. Fairly simple.

Aside from simplicity, another advantage is that python and this API are all preinstalled and come with Ubuntu by default.

Answer (score 6):

You *can* actually do this in `sed`, but I strongly urge you to use a more sophisticated language that has tools written to handle JSON data. You could try perl or python, for example.

Now, in your simple example, all you want is the first occurrence of `"status"`, so you could do:

```
$ sed -nE '/status/{s/.*:\s*"(.*)",/\1/p;q}' file.json 
ERROR
```

The trick is to use `-n` to avoid printing, then if the line matches `status` (`/status/`), you remove everything but the part you want `s/.*:\s*"(.*)",/\1/`, `p`rint the line and `q`uit.

---

Personally, I find this equivalent grep command much simpler:

```
$ grep -m1 -oP '"status"\s*:\s*"\K[^"]+' file.json 
ERROR
```

Or this one:

```
$ perl -ne 'if(s/.*"status"\s*:\s*"([^"]+).*/$1/){print;exit}' file.json 
ERROR
```

Seriously though, if you plan to be parsing JSON files, do not try to do this manually. Use a proper JSON parser.

Comment: or this one: `grep -m 1 status file.json | tr -cd '[[:alnum:]]:'  | cut -f2 -d':'`

Comment: @user1876040 you're welcome. Please remember to accept one of the answers (I recommend [ByteCommander's](http://askubuntu.com/a/863872/85695), his is a better solution) so the question can be marked as answered).

Answer (score 6):

Not saying you *should* use `sed` (I think someone has downvoted me just for not writing obligatory caveat) but, if you need to search for something on the *next* line to `buildStatus` as you seem to be trying in your own attempt, you need to tell `sed` to read the next line with the `N` command

```
$ sed -rn '/buildStatus/N;s/.*buildStatus.*\n.*: "(.*)",/\1/p' file
ERROR
```

#### Notes:

- `-n` don't print anything until we ask for it
- `-r` use ERE (same as `-E`)
- `/buildStatus/N` find this pattern and read the next line too
- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*` any number of any characters on the line
- `\n` newline
- `: "(.*)",` save any characters occurring between `: "` and `",`
- `\1` back reference to saved pattern
- `p` print the part we worked on

Answer (score 0):

There is a typical explanation of why `sed` and similar text stream processing tools are not well equipped to parse structured data such as JSON and XML.  I do not have that on-hand, but it is out there, and I believe the point to be that the expressions needed in all but probably the fewest of situations quickly become very complex, while alternative tools built specifically for parsing the structure are more elegant, readable, and efficient at the same parsing.

Like [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) has put [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863865/regex-with-sed-command-to-parse-json-text#comment1334185_863872), `jq` should be the right tool for the job.
I can also vouch for it personally being very excited to see it replace several times where I have tried parsing the same data to no almost no or burdened success. It even contains a large about of capability for formatting and otherwise controlling the output.
I prefer it to `jsontool` for a reason or more that I currently forget.

[Byte Commander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander) seems to recommend `jshon` in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/863872/230721).  I have not used that tool, but it reminds me of `xmlstarlet` and its syntax, also with some customizable presentation for the output.

Comment: You're probably talking of http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2072269

Comment: Consider improving your answer by showing example of how `jsontool` can be used for OP's specific case

Comment: Lol @muru, correct, that is one of the posts attempting to deter uses from parsing XML/JSON with Regex!

I was more recommending `jq` that muru and heemayl describe that already have exmaples, and just posting the reasoning behind it: http://askubuntu.com/a/863948/230721

Answer (score 0):

Just another Json tool called json (https://github.com/trentm/json)

```
$ json buildStatus.status < file.json
ERROR
```

This case study is misleading: it looks like tools are not working.
You can also use `json` for changing json files:

```
$ json -e 'this.buildStatus.status="not error"' < file.json > new.json
```

or even...

```
$ json -e 'this.buildStatus.status="no errors"' < file.json | json -e 'this.buildStatus.status
no errors
```

documentation in: http://trentm.com/json/

---

if not installed:

- install node
- and sudo `npm install -g json`